# Load more cells problem

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, uitableview

i use MWFeedParser library to parse xml.
when i change the numberOfRowsInSection to +1 (return [itemsToDisplay count] +1;)
to make the last cell row for the Load more option my app crash in this line:
MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wel you are trying the get an item from an array that is beyond the the number of items in that array. (also accept some anser, people are more willing to anser if you accept answers)

Ex:
You do a plus 1 in the `numberOfRowsInSection` which, by example, return 11.
That means that there are 10 item in the `itemsToDisplay` array.
You are retrieving item from the `itemsToDisplay` in with `MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` but you cant retrieve item number 11 because it does not exists.

In the `- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
if (indexPath.row < [itemsToDisplay count]) {
   MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // Set the cell here
} else {
   //create a cell with the text "Load More"
}
```

Comment: tnx for the quick answer :) now i know the problem but how do i fix it?